# Take values from dropdown and display it in a text box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have two drop down menus,

1>   `<select id="building">`

2>`<select id="level">`

**level** is updated using jquery every time the value of **building** is changed.

I also want to display the values selected in the drop down menus into two textboxes.

How may i be able to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever one of the selects changes - update the textbox:

```
var updateTextbox() = function() {
    buildingVal = $("#building").val();
    levelVal = $("#level").val();
    $("#mybuildingtextbox").val(buildingVal);
    $("#myleveltextbox").val(levelVal);
}

$("#building").change(updateTextbox);
//or if you're already using one of the change events:
$("#level").change(function() {
    //the rest of your code
    updateTextbox();
}
```

Edit: did not notice you said two textboxes - not much of a change. And you should consider adding a [jquery] tag to the question.